# Selenium webdriver error : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_capabilities'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to run the following lines of code on Python, but I am thrown the error :

```
  Cell In[11], line 10
    driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url,options)

  File ~/anaconda3/envs/algo/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:189 in __init__
    capabilities = options.to_capabilities()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_capabilities'
```

Would be very helpful if anyone can share thoughts on resolving this!

Code:

```
    token_path = "api_key.txt"
    key_secret = open(token_path,'r').read().split()
    kite = KiteConnect(api_key = key_secret[0])
    service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service('./chromedriver')
    service.start()
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options = options.to_capabilities()
    driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url,options)
    driver.get(kite.login_url())
```

Comment: Apparently, `webdriver.ChromeOptions()` is `None`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
from selenium import webdriver

token_path = "api_key.txt"
key_secret = open(token_path, 'r').read().split()
kite = KiteConnect(api_key=key_secret[0])
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service('./chromedriver')
service.start()
driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url, 
desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities() if options else None)
driver.get(kite.login_url())
```